# Unable to install Tomcat 7 on Ubunu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, tomcat7

I am trying to install Tomcat 7 on my Dell Dimention 3000 running Wubi 12.04 (not a server). I found instructions here:
`http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/`,
but can not get past step 1A. I get a 404 error when it trys to install some packages.

This is the code I used to install:
    sudo apt-get install tomcat7

This is a log of my terminal window:

```
Script started on Wed 04 May 2016 07:23:33 PM CDT
]0;username@ubuntu: ~username@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install tomcat7
[sudo] password for username: 

Reading package lists... 0%

Reading package lists... 100%

Reading package lists... Done


Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 1%

Building dependency tree... 2%

Building dependency tree... 3%

Building dependency tree... 4%

Building dependency tree... 5%

Building dependency tree... 7%

Building dependency tree... 14%

Building dependency tree... 32%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree... 51%

Building dependency tree... 52%

Building dependency tree... 53%

Building dependency tree... 54%

Building dependency tree... 55%

Building dependency tree... 56%

Building dependency tree... 57%

Building dependency tree... 58%

Building dependency tree... 59%

Building dependency tree... 60%

Building dependency tree... 61%

Building dependency tree... 62%

Building dependency tree... 63%

Building dependency tree... 64%

Building dependency tree... 66%

Building dependency tree... 68%

Building dependency tree... 69%

Building dependency tree... 71%

Building dependency tree... 74%

Building dependency tree... 77%

Building dependency tree... 87%

Building dependency tree       


Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... 2%

Reading state information... Done

The following extra packages will be installed:
  authbind ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao
  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm java-common libcommons-collections3-java
  libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-pool-java libecj-java libnss3 libnss3-1d
  libservlet3.0-java libtomcat7-java openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib
  tomcat7-common tzdata tzdata-java
Suggested packages:
  default-jre equivs libcommons-collections3-java-doc
  libgeronimo-jta-1.0.1b-spec-java ecj ant libecj-java-gcj sun-java6-fonts
  ttf-dejavu-extra fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-telugu-fonts
  ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts tomcat7-docs
  tomcat7-admin tomcat7-examples tomcat7-user libtcnative-1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  authbind ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao
  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm java-common libcommons-collections3-java
  libcommons-dbcp-java libcommons-pool-java libecj-java libnss3-1d
  libservlet3.0-java libtomcat7-java openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib
  tomcat7 tomcat7-common tzdata-java
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnss3 tzdata
2 upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 237 not upgraded.
Need to get 44.5 MB/50.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 71.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y


0% [Working]

0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.26)]

Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libnss3 i386 2:3.21-0ubuntu0.12.04.3 [1,244 kB]


0% [1 libnss3 0 B/1,244 kB 0%]

3% [Working]

Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main openjdk-6-jre-lib all 6b38-1.13.10-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [6,258 kB]


3% [2 openjdk-6-jre-lib 0 B/6,258 kB 0%]

10% [2 openjdk-6-jre-lib 3,420 kB/6,258 kB 55%]

17% [Working]

Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libnss3-1d i386 2:3.21-0ubuntu0.12.04.3 [13.4 kB]


17% [3 libnss3-1d 0 B/13.4 kB 0%]

17% [Working]

Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main tzdata all 2016c-0ubuntu0.12.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]


17% [Working]                                               29.1 kB/s           21min 11s

Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main openjdk-6-jre-headless i386 6b38-1.13.10-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [35.1 MB]


Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main icedtea-6-jre-cacao i386 6b38-1.13.10-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [771 kB]


Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main icedtea-6-jre-jamvm i386 6b38-1.13.10-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [553 kB]

99% [Working]                                                     29.1     kB/s 19s

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main tzdata all 2016c-0ubuntu0.12.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

99% [Working]                                                     29.1 kB/s 19s

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main tzdata-java all 2016c-0ubuntu0.12.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

99% [Working]                                                     29.1 kB/s 19s

Fetched 43.9 MB in 4min 19s (169 kB/s)
Failed to fetch     http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2016c-    0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Failed to fetch     http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata-java_2016c-0ubuntu0.12.04_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
]0;username@ubuntu: ~username@ubuntu:~$ exit\\\[K[K[K[K[K[K[Kexit
exit

Script done on Wed 04 May 2016 07:38:30 PM CDT
```

Comment: @sinclair 12.04 is an LTS release supported through April 2017; please keep comments on AskUbuntu respectful and constructive.

Comment: @vikarjramun Please try running `sudo apt-get update` to update your package lists. Does it give any errors? If not, then try running `sudo apt-get install tomcat7` again

Comment: @NickWeinberg Did not mean to be disrespectful, but yes you got a point.

Comment: @NickWeinberg I did that, but received the following error: `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)` and `E: unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg), is another process using it?` I will retry this

Comment: @NickWeinburg the `apt-get update` worked for me the second time: I am now in the process of installing tomcat7 Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @NickWeinberg You might want to convert your comment that solved his issue to an answer.

Comment: @Zzzach... done! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your package lists. Does it give any errors?

If not, then try running

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

again. This should hopefully fix your problem.